# I want to use the "car" array , car[ : 250, :200, : ] to convert into image .Car array shape is (431, 575, 4)

Tags: python, numpy

Please see the code here:

[image]

I want to use the packages already imported

Comment: you have to use Pillow for that, but just search for that and give it a try... :)

Comment: things are different in pillow, when i convert the image to array in pillow, the array is different from the one in image, it has only integers, but i got the answer in pillow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show or display the image you can use [imshow](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html?highlight=imshow#matplotlib-pyplot-imshow)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(car[:250, :200, :])
```

If you want to save a new image to disk you can use [imsave](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/image_api.html#matplotlib.image.imsave).

```py
from matplotlib.image import imsave
imsave("new_car_image.png", car[:250, :200, :])
```